# Insert arbitrary values into AutoNumber field via OleDbDataAdapter.Update

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, insert

I have a table like this in my Access Database

```
id  name    address     date
1   first   addresss    5/6/2005 9:17:52 AM
2   test1   address1    5/11/2005 5:23:32 AM
3   test22  address2    5/11/2006 5:23:32 AM
8   test3   address3    5/11/2007 5:23:32 AM
9   test4   address4    5/11/2008 5:23:32 AM
13  test    address     5/11/2008 5:23:32 AM
```

Here, `id` filed is an `Primary Key` - `AutoNumber` field. Now, how can I insert a record with an id **11** into this table using `C#` ?

When I try insertions with id under 13 or above 14 the next inserted value will be 14. What happens if I want to insert a deleted record back into the table ?

Any workarounds or actual solutions addressing this problem will be appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

Its good to hear that its possible to insert, values into an `AutoNumber` field. Here is the function that I use to make bulk insertions. The DataTable has the same column names with similar data types. The code works however as I said above, the primary keys are assigned automatically.

Might there be any kind of fix for this particular code ?

```
public void AccessBulkCopy(DataTable table)
{
    foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
        r.SetAdded();

    var myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + table.TableName, _myAccessConn);

    var cbr = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myAdapter);
    cbr.QuotePrefix = "[";
    cbr.QuoteSuffix = "]";
    cbr.GetInsertCommand(true);

    myAdapter.Update(table);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you used to insert a value of 11 in your table

Comment: In MS Access, you can use an INSERT INTO <table, column1, column2, ... columnx) VALUES (value1, value2, .... valuex) statement whereas the first column represents your autonumber column. I'm not familiar with c# but this should help you on your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Access Database Engine **does** indeed allow us to use SQL to insert arbitrary values into an AutoNumber field. The following will work in your case, provided that there isn't already a row in the table with [id]=11:

```cs
string sql = "INSERT INTO [YourTable] ([id], [name]) VALUES (?,?)";
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", 11);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "Gord");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**Edit**

With your `OleDbDataAdapter`, the `InsertCommand` that is automatically generated by the `OleDbCommandBuilder` recognizes that [id] is an AutoNumber column and omits it from the CommandText (`"INSERT INTO ..."`). So, the "id" column in your `DataTable` was being ignored and you were getting automatically-assigned [id] values.

If you want the [id] column included in the INSERT then you need to create your own [OleDbDataAdapter.InsertCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) like so:

```cs
using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [id], [name] FROM [YourTable] WHERE 1=0", conn))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    var cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [YourTable] ([id], [name]) VALUES (?,?)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "id"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255, "name"));
    da.InsertCommand = cmd;

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["id"] = 11;
    dr["name"] = "Gord";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    da.Update(dt);
}
```

Comment: Do you think the reason my code acts like that is something to do with database connection type ? I see you use Odbc connection whereas my code uses OleDb.

Comment: No, Odbc and OleDb are similar in this respect. The difference was that you were using an OleDbCommandBuilder. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't.   An auto-number, primary key field in MS Access should not ever be edited or changed.  Even if you found a hack around it, it's bad practice.  Some SQL databases have workarounds that allow it.

Typically what we do is never to delete out of the table.  Instead, have a field, perhaps a text field, maybe a single character, that indicates A for Active, or D for deleted.

Then setup a view (a query) that returns all the fields, but only the active rows.  You can then do all your reports, forms, queries, work, on that view.

When you need to insert a deleted row back, then you have a special update that changes the deleted status back to active.

Comment: Well, all correct, but what is correct is not always true. MS-Access is not the only database that allows a direct insert onto an autonumber field. So your _you can't_ should be changed to _you shouldn't_

Comment: @steve I believe that Access won't let you update a auto-number field.  Did you mean to say that other databases allow it?  I changed my answer to be clearer that I was just speaking about Access.

Comment: For MS-Access you can do an INSERT INTO and specify the AUTONUMBER column setting for it the value you like. Of course being the AUTONUMBER column also a Primary Key you cannot insert an existing value. Sadly you can INSERT a number higher than the last one stored and face the error when the autoincrementing number reaches the manually inserted value (Happened). MySql also allows you to specify the manual value but it handles the next generated id correctly (or at least doesn't allow to insert an higher number - not sure at the moment), for SQL SERVER you just call IDENTITY_INSERT ON and OFF

Comment: However I agree that this is just a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: Perhaps I should also add that this happens using code (OleDb....). The MS-Access GUI doesn't allow you to do anything like that

Comment: OP asks about inserting a non existing value back to the table, your answer starts with "you can't". Sorry that's a wrong answer!! manual insertion is possible!

Comment: @Knox Maybe its not a good practice but don't forget, by deleting records in a table where there is going to be a lot of deletion to happen, helps the database size not to grow. Especially for MS Access with 2 GB limitation this is a very important fact. Sometimes some stuff are exaggerated.

Comment: @0014 Good point.  The only reason i suggested the whole active/deleted status was to manage if a deleted row might need to be restored.   I certainly have tables with an autonumber where i delete rows.  Good point.

Comment: krishKM @steve  I learn something everyday.  I didn't know it was possible to modify autonumber fields using the direct engine.